# cross initialization of map iterator in a switch case

Tags: c++, iterator, switch-statement

Recently i was trying out a program using `std::map` and came across a situation where I needed to use the map `iterator` in a switch case. My program goes like this :-

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() 
{
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    map<string,int> m;
    //map<string,int>::iterator itr;
    int q, mark, type;
    string name;
    cin >> q;
    while (q--)
    {
        cin >> type;
        switch (type)
        {
            case 1: cin >> name >> mark;
                    m[name] += mark;
                    break;
            case 2: cin >> name;
                    m.erase(name);
                    break;
            case 3: cin >> name;
                    auto itr = m.find(name);
                    if (itr != m.end())
                        cout << itr->second << '\n';
                    else
                        cout << "0";
                    break;                             // problem lies here
            default: cout << "ERROR !!!\n"; break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For this code my compiler flashes an error :-

```
Error] crosses initialization of 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> > itr'
```

If I declare the `iterator itr` outside the `switch case` then the codee compiles properly. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this method ???

Comment: Since the `cin >> name` is used in each case I recommend moving the statement before the `switch` statement.  This is called factoring out common code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it's based on a specific problem actually
the name has to be input after the type, that's why everytime i'm pushing in `cin`
for more details see this:-
`https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cpp-maps`

Comment: So, move the `cin >> name` after the `cin >> type`. Or combine them: `cin >> type >> name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider that in C and C++ a `switch` is implemented based on `goto` and you are not allowed have a `goto` skipping the initialization of an object.

Just wrap each `case` in a block `{ ... }` and everything should be fine. The case creating the problem is the one with the `itr`.

```
switch (type) 
{
    case 1: {
        cin >> name >> mark;
        m[name] += mark;
        break;
    }
    ...
    case 3: {
        cin >> name;
        auto itr = m.find(name);
        ...
        break;      
    }
    ...
}
```